# button click event not working when side menu is open ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a cordova ionic app with side menu. By default, I need to keep side menu open. When I click on a button on page, it doesn't work. I have click twice on the page. First time when i click on button, side menu closes, then i have to click on button again to perform the operation. How can i make it work even if the side menu is open.

**SideMenu.html**

```
    <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" class="menu-page">
      <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-back-button>
     <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
   </ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-side-menu-content>
 <ion-side-menu side="left" class="left-nav">

   <ion-content scroll="false"  has-bouncing="false">
    <div class="user-info text-center">

   </div>
     <ion-list>
          <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="app.menuscreen" ui-sref-active="selected">
             <i class="ion-home"></i><span>Home</span>
         </a>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**app.js**

```
     .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider

             .state('app', {
               url: '/app',
               abstract: true,
              templateUrl: 'templates/sidemenu.html',
           })

            .state('app.menuscreen', {
               url: '/menuscreen',
               views: {
                   'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/menuscreen.html',
                  }
            }
           })
```

**MenuScreen.html**

```
            <ion-view> 
            <ion-content has-bouncing="false">

            <div class="button-box">
                <h2>Would you like to?</h2>
                <!--Button-->
                <div class="btn-box">
                    <div class="btn-parent-box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button button-full btn-orange" type="submit"
                            ui-sref="newjob" title="New Job">New Job</button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/button-->
            </div>
            </ion-content> 
            </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using menu-close better to user menu-toggle="left" / menu-toggle="right" based on your menu have and you can use that button event for some code. What all you have to do is,

```
 <button class="button button-full btn-orange" type="submit" menu-toggle="left" ui-sref="newjob" title="New Job">New Job</button>
```

in the menu, what ever so called list is add

```
menu-toggle="left".
```

that's it. And you can able to perform all operation.

If correct vote for it.

Comment: Thanks @Nitin Agarwal. As i too was searching for it.

Comment: @Nitin its not working in my case... I have replaced menu-close with menu-toggle="left" but due to this when I am navigating...navigation icon at the top is getting changed to back button...

Comment: So you can what is your question. If you dont want that, just remove the ion-nav-back-button. That's it. or else share you code with plunker / jsfiddle